# VLOOKUP for 2 sheets in single workbook

Tags: excel, formatting, formula, vlookup

I'm trying to apply a VLOOKUP formula on OPS Ticket column which is the common lookup value in 2 sheets. I would like to retrieve column E of **OPS Tickets created** sheet (*which is hidden due to business reasons and is identical to F column*).

I tried the following formula:
    =VLOOKUP(E2,'OPS Tickets Created'!$D$2:$E$1147,5,0)
However, it doesn't retrieve any values. When I check manually, there are matching ticket numbers in both the sheets.

Could someone share thoughts on the formula ?!

[image]
[image]

Comment: 'OPS Tickets Created'!$D$2:$E$1147 is only 2 columns wide so you cannot retrieve something at position 5. Only 1 or 2.

Comment: Maybe you should hide column G in the second picture ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
 =VLOOKUP(E2,'OPS Tickets Created'!$D$2:$E$1147,2,0)
```

`'OPS Tickets Created'!$D$2:$E$1147` is only 2 columns wide so you cannot retrieve something at position 5. Only 1 or 2.

If not found, wrap in an IFERROR  statement to give an alternative message to user (rather than #N/A)

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,'OPS Tickets Created'!$D$2:$E$1147,2,0),"Not Found")
```

Comment: I mistook with the position of the column. It worked now! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Can I replace 'NA' with a text saying 'Not Found' ?!

Comment: see edit to answer though haven't tested i have typed correctly.